# cd rom update issue

Tags: updates, cd

I am having a problem with my cd rom not working or getting updates for it I went to the update manager and this is what I read when I went to settings.

```
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20140204)/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20140204)/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Dose anyone know what this means?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This means that your CDROM is listed as a source to "download" packages from. If you go into your "Ubuntu Software Center" and edit your Sources / disable CDROM, you will not get these errors anymore.